# Create a cell depending on size of a matrix {in MATLAB}

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a cell in the following form...

```
{'x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7','x8'}
```

If the size of my matrix j is 10, I would like,

```
{'x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7','x8','x9','x10'}
```

if the size of my matrix j is 3 I would like,

```
{'x1','x2','x3'}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [mre], especially provide some code you tested by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`compose`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/compose.html).

```
>> compose('x%i', 1:10)
ans =
  1×10 cell array
    {'x1'}    {'x2'}    {'x3'}    {'x4'}    {'x5'}    {'x6'}    {'x7'}    {'x8'}    {'x9'}    {'x10'}
```